# Writing JavaScript for automatization - node.click() is not enough - page still think that no radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, wikimedia-commons

I am writing my userscript for Wikiedia Commons, for this block:[image]

I tried

```
node.click()

node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))

node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, view: window}))
```

And visually the correct radio button is selected, but when pressing `Next` I am getting error

> Selection is required

[image]

So, for some reasong, JS click() is not the same as human click?

Comment: A js click() wont trigger any other event handlers attached to the element. It might be the case that the code doesn't use the radio's value but rather a script assigns a value based on which radio was clicked. If so, emitting a click wont trigger that script, as to avoid a chain reaction.

Comment: @GetSet thanks, so, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by clicking to another element:

```
const knowledge = document.querySelector('[value="knowledge"]')
if (knowledge && knowledge.checked == false) {
    knowledge.parentNode.nextSibling.click()
}
```